# Pandas CSV to Django Response

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have a DataFrame generated from a database. How do I provide a response wherein it downloads a CSV?

Basically,

```
df = magic_dataframe_supplier()
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=export.csv'

# ... type mapping code ...

return response
```

I've got a working version with `csv.writer` but for obvious reasons, that is not a `DataFrame`. And I'm unclear on how exactly I can turn a `df` into such an object.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Given:

```
df = magic_dataframe_supplier()
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=export.csv'  # alter as needed
```

Just write:

```
df.to_csv(path_or_buf=response)  # with other applicable parameters
return response
```

Pandas writes the data frame to CSV in the response buffer and then Django serves the response.

**Compression.** Pandas does not permit the passing of non-none `compression` parameters, as it cannot determine the compression type from a buffer, which is not a path. Instead, for compression, one would have to write the file to a text wrapper which is then compressed using Python's `gzip` library. That object would then be served as the archive. Code similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44168817/2741091), adapted for Django, would be necessary.

Answer (score -2):

I believe that the object type "DataFrame" does not exist in javascript. You may want to try JSON instead to transmit your data.

Comment: This isn't JavaScript. This Django.

Comment: Yes. But what django does is "converting" your response into httpresponse, javascript and json, before sending it over to the client side. As you can see, you used "Content-Disposition", this is part of a json response.

On top of that, you noticed that you are also using the "attachment" format. I believe that "Dataframe" does not have a format. It is a python-based object type but not an actual format.

Comment: That's correct, but you can write the Dataframe to the response by passing the response to `pd.to_csv`

Comment: Yes. It will be passed as a CSV format and not a Dataframe format.

Comment: On the receiving end, just use the pd.read_csv(URL_LINK) and you will be good to go. Do note that this only works as csv and not xlsx.

Comment: Are you trying to find out how to pass the Dataframe into the response ? Or receiving it? You did not really specific a question

Comment: Not sure how my question of `I have a DataFrame generated from a database. How do I provide a response wherein it downloads a CSV?` got turned into `How do I serialise a Pandas dataframe across the web to another computer`, but okay. I happened to discover the answer to this question a long time ago, which shouldn't be a surprise given its age. The answer is above.