# CSV to .GZ using Cloud function, Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I've been trying to compress my CSV files to .gz before uploading to GCS using Cloud Function-Python 3.7, but what my code does only adds the .gz extension but doesn't really compress the file, so in the end, the file was corrupted. Can you please show me how to fix this? Thanks

here is part of my code

```
import gzip


def to_gcs(request):    
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
    gcs_filename = 'filename_{}.csv'
    bucket_name = 'bucket_gcs_name'
    subfolder = 'subfolder_name'
    client = bigquery.Client()


    job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE

    QUERY = "SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*` session, UNNEST(hits) AS hits"
    query_job = client.query(
        QUERY,
        location='US',
        job_config=job_config)

    while not query_job.done():
        time.sleep(1)

    rows_df = query_job.result().to_dataframe()
    storage_client = storage.Client()

    storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name).blob(subfolder+'/'+gcs_filename+'.gz').upload_from_string(rows_df.to_csv(sep='|',index=False,encoding='utf-8',compression='gzip'), content_type='application/octet-stream')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write pandas dataframe as compressed CSV directly to Amazon s3 bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43729224/write-pandas-dataframe-as-compressed-csv-directly-to-amazon-s3-bucket)

Comment: you should check the warnings you're getting from Pandas, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44168817/1358308 and https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22555

Comment: The most voted answer from @SamMason 's first comment did work for me. Did that work for you @Justine?

Comment: @Jose V, it does!

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer as community wiki (so I won't get any reputation) with the info from @Sam Mason's comment. If the answer solves your issue, please consider [accepting and/or upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it so that the community sees it. Feel free to edit it if you see fit.

Comment: @JoseV I've had a fiddle and added a note about using the `tempfile` module.  also the [`upload_from_string` method](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/_modules/google/cloud/storage/blob.html#Blob.upload_from_string) immediately creates a `BytesIO` object so it's better passing a file object if possible, which is now trivial

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43729224/write-pandas-dataframe-as-compressed-csv-directly-to-amazon-s3-bucket) referred by @Sam Mason in a comment, once you have obtained the Pandas datafame, you should use a `TextIOWrapper()` and `BytesIO()` as described in the following sample:

> The following sample was inspired by @ramhiser's answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43729224/write-pandas-dataframe-as-compressed-csv-directly-to-amazon-s3-bucket) SO thread

```
df = query_job.result().to_dataframe()
blob = bucket.blob(f'{subfolder}/{gcs_filename}.gz')

with BytesIO() as gz_buffer:
    with gzip.GzipFile(mode='w', fileobj=gz_buffer) as gz_file:
        df.to_csv(TextIOWrapper(gz_file, 'utf8'), index=False)

    blob.upload_from_file(gz_buffer,
        content_type='application/octet-stream')
```

also note that if you expect this file to ever get larger than a couple of MB you are probably better off using something from the [`tempfile` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) in place of `BytesIO`.  [`SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) is basically designed for this use case, where it will use a memory buffer up to some given size and only use the disk if the file gets really big

Comment: For people facing `ValueError: Stream must be at beginning` use insert gz_buffer.seek(0) before the `blob.upload_from_file(...)` line.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried to reproduce your use case:

1. I created a cloud function using this quickstart [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-python):

   ```
   def hello_world(request):

     from google.cloud import bigquery
     from google.cloud import storage 
     import pandas as pd 


     client = bigquery.Client() 
     storage_client = storage.Client() 

     path = '/tmp/file.gz'


     query_job = client.query("""
     SELECT
     CONCAT(
       'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/',
        CAST(id as STRING)) as url,
     view_count
     FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions`
     WHERE tags like '%google-bigquery%'
     ORDER BY view_count DESC
     LIMIT 10""")  

     results = query_job.result().to_dataframe()
     results.to_csv(path,sep='|',index=False,encoding='utf-8',compression='gzip')

     bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('mybucket')  
     blob = bucket.blob('file.gz')
     blob.upload_from_filename(path)
   ```

   2. This is the `requirements.txt`:

      ```
      # Function dependencies, for example:

      google-cloud-bigquery
      google-cloud-storage
      pandas
      ```
   3. I deployed the function.
   4. I checked the output.

      ```
      gsutil cp gs://mybucket/file.gz file.gz
      gzip -d file.gz
      cat file


      #url|view_count
      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879669|52306
      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530967|46073
      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159967|45991
      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604135|45238
      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609219|37758
      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647201|32963
      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221978|32507
      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060396|31630
      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607552|31487
      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057219|29069
      ```